# Raw_input in Python not returning (Sublime Text 3)

Tags: python, sublimetext3, raw-input

I am using Sublime Text 3. This is my code:

```
a = raw_input("Test raw: ")
```

It correctly asks for Test raw: but does not do anything after entering a letter. This line, however, works in command prompt.

Basically, after Test raw: displays and I enter a character, I want it to move on the next line. Right now, it does not. I can just keep entering characters without it moving on.

**Edit:** SublimeREPL is for Sublime Text 2. I could not install it for Sublime Text 3. Is there something similar?

**Answer:** Use this [website](https://realpython.com/blog/python/setting-up-sublime-text-3-for-full-stack-python-development) to install package control and follow the rest of the instructions [here](http://www.bestpythonide.com/python-input-eoferror-in-sublime-text-2.html). Thanks everyone!

Comment: This line works in the command prompt because of the Python Read-Evaluate-**Print**-Loop, but will not work in a file because it is never printed. See @James's answer.

Comment: [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) is not supposed to return until it encounters a line separator (when you press Enter). Are you pressing Enter?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your editor btw.

Comment: I am pressing enter but still not getting an answer.

Comment: What were you expecting it to do? You haven't told Python to display any output or anything.

Comment: Oh, I see you're using Sublime Text. I think that's a Sublime Text problem you're running into.

Comment: @user2357112 do you have any suggestions abt how to fix this?

Comment: @Shivani: Probably install SublimeREPL, like the answers in the link suggest.

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work :( I am using Sublime Text 3

Comment: @Shivani SublimeREPL works just fine with Sublime Text 3. Install it through Package Control.

Answer (score 0):

In the command prompt (use known as the Python REPL, for "read evaluate print loop"), if an expression is left hanging, its representation will be printed after evaluation finishes - hence the "read, evaluate **print**, loop".

That's not true of a Python program. In the Python program, the input is assigned to a, then the program finishes. To make it print, do:

```
a = raw_input("Test raw: ")
print(a)
```

Or simply

```
print(raw_input("Test raw: "))
```

To skip using the variable altogether

Comment: Thanks. However, it does not move on to the next line. For example, if the code is "a = raw_input("Test raw: ")
print 'b'", it never prints 'b' even after entering something for Test raw:

Comment: Well, for starters, b will be undefined so it will error out there, and also it won't move onto the next line until it receives input.

Comment: Even after I put in input though, it does not move on. Also it is 'b', not a variable b

Comment: `a = raw_input(whatever)` won't print the value of `a` in the REPL either. The REPL only prints the value of expression statements, and this is an assignment statement.

Comment: From your question, it looks like James' answer correctly answers the question. However, from your reply, it seems that is not what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe we can assist better with a little more detail for what you are trying to achieve.  For example, do you want to have a continue receiving input and then print all data given?

Comment: Ok, more specifically my question is about moving on after this line. It does not need to print the output but it does not need to end at some point. Even after I enter a letter and hit 'Enter', it does not end. It simply allows you to keep entering input.